# ARM64 AESE instruction create a SIGILL

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm, arm64, raspberry-pi4

On a Raspberry 4, when compiling and executing an assembly file containing only this instruction:

```
aese v0.16b, v1.16b
```

the program crashes because of a SIGILL. What would be the problem here? Is it possible that not all ARM64 processors support the AES instruction set?

Some relevant informations:

`.arch armv8-a+crypto` was added at the beginning of the file.

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 5.15.32-v8+ #1538 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 31 19:40:39 BST 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux

$ cat /proc/cpuinfo 
processor   : 0
BogoMIPS    : 108.00
Features    : fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3

processor   : 1
BogoMIPS    : 108.00
Features    : fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3

processor   : 2
BogoMIPS    : 108.00
Features    : fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3

processor   : 3
BogoMIPS    : 108.00
Features    : fp asimd evtstrm crc32 cpuid
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 8
CPU variant : 0x0
CPU part    : 0xd08
CPU revision    : 3

Hardware    : BCM2835
Revision    : c03115
Serial      : 1000000005fa511b
Model       : Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.5
```

Comment: If your CPU supported the AES extension, you would see `aes` on the `Features` line for each core.  So evidently it does not.

Answer (score 2):

The Rasberry Pi 4 doesn't implement the crypto instruction set extensions, so any attempt to use them will result in an undefined instruction exception.

> Is it possible that not all ARM64 processors support the AES instruction set?

Yes definitely possible, it's an optional feature.

Comment: Well, damn then. Thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: @Katoptriss: That's why `+crypto` is separate from the `armv8-a` baseline in the `.arch` directive.